# RxAndroid - save data when activity is destroyed

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Consider this scenario:

- Perform computational heavy task at Activity1 (assume it takes 20 seconds)
- User killed Activity1 at 10th second
- When task gets completed, save the data in Database. (UI updation not required)

Now, since `subscription.unsubscribe();` gets called on `OnDestory();`, I was unable to save the data in Database.

**Question:**
What is the best pattern, so that there shouldn't be data loss after tasks get completed?

Comment: Perform computational heavy task at Activity1? I think you should have a look at `JobIntentService`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, as long as you don't expect to see the result of the operation in the current `Activity` and operation is really long, you shouldn't call it within the `Activity`. In my opinion, you should perform this operation inside a `Service`, which can be invoked from the `Activity`. You can use RxJava inside a `Service` as well. When the operation is done, you can send a notification to the `Activity` or somewhere else (e.g. via Event Bus like Otto or via custom `BroadcastReceiver` or via custom Event Bus implemented with RxJava). In such case, you will be independent of the `Activity` life cycle and operation will be executed regardless of the fact that one `Activity` was destroyed or paused.